# Как починить доступ в админку Django после установки SSL и HTTPS?

Tags: python, django

Я опубликовал сайт на сервере и все доступы и формы работали, но после установки `SSL` и редиректов любое заполнение формы, включая вход в админ панель выдает ошибку -

> Forbidden (403) CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.

Посмотрел все текущие рекомендации, добавил в `settings.py`
CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = ['http://wherefilmed.org/','https://wherefilmed.org/']

Далее добавил строчку  '

```
django.middleware.csrf.CsrfResponseMiddleware',
в MIDDLEWARE = []
```

Проверил, что `{% csrf_token %}` находится во всех формах.

Comment: Читайте в логах Django, по какой конкретно причине CSRF verification оказался failed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все дело оказалось в неправильной настройке SSL. Проблему решил через установку на хостинге выделенного IP и привязки домена к нему. После этого все установилось нормально и все доступы заработали.